# Почему вывод функции возвращает "function info at 0x0000024B3B3EE040"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Начинаю изучать питон, у меня возникли проблемы с выводом программы
Вот простая функция:

```
def info(age):

    if age <= 16:
        print('Учись в школе')
    else:
        print('Поступай дальше')
info(18)
print(info)
info(15)
print(info)
```

Вывод получается вот такой:

```
Поступай дальше
<function info at 0x0000024B3B3EE040>
Учись в школе
<function info at 0x0000024B3B3EE040>
```

У меня вопрос.
Что это такое при выводе в функции

```
<function info at 0x0000024B3B3EE040>
<function info at 0x0000024B3B3EE040>
```

Что я сделал не так?

Comment: Ну вы через `print(info)` выводите на консоль сам объект функции, не вызывая саму функцию, выводится ее краткое описание. Просто не делайте этот print.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы выводите объект функции, а не вызываете её.

```
def info(age):

    if age <= 16:
        print('Учись в школе')
    else:
        print('Поступай дальше')
info(18)
info(15)
```

Если вы будете вызывать функцию `print(info(18))`, то будет выводиться None. Т.к функция ничего не возвращает.